# Control Execution Order of AOP and @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I am using spring boot 2.0.8 in a web application. I have methods in a Controller annotated with @Transactional. I also have an AOP @Around for the same method. In my testing I observe the AOP advise called inside the transaction (before my transaction revision coordinator gets called).

How can I change the order with the AOP advise executed before and after the transaction? From previous postings, it appears that @Order can be used but I am not seeing any differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it help if you set `@EnableTransactionManagement(order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`? Or maybe the logic is somehow reverse and you need to set lowest precedence, I did not try. But lowest precedence should be the default already.

See also these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485722/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509777/1082681

See also these bits of Spring Javadoc:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html#order--
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html#HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE